# how can make a batch file that will mount a iso file?

Tags: batch-file, mount, iso, cmp

I have a ISO game file that I have to mount with virtual clone drive every time I turn on the computer. So I want to make a simple batch file that mounts the ISO file with the VCD program automatically. With this I can click on the batch and let it do the "extensive" work for me :P. All help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you not set ISO's to open with VCD and call the file from the batch file?

Comment: If you use a program like Alcohol or Daemon Tools (and also Daemon Tools Lite) they both have an option to remount any images on boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really have to use that VCD program you could try FileDisk utility:
http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/

Here are some usage examples: http://david.gardiner.net.au/2007/10/mounting-iso-files-from-command-line.html

Comment: Thanks for the information but it seems like I found a auto mount option in the VCD program. I appreciate your help and I should of over looked at the program first before I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
explorer.exe  c:\Image.iso
```

I don't know how to make it use a specific drive letter - it looks like it just uses the first available.